# Unreachable Statement In Java after Adding external Jar file

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I  created a Maven java project in IntelliJIdea, add my own external jar file and try to access the class from the added jar file. But shows the error called Unreachable Statment.

[image]

Comment: The error message has a meaning. It means that one of the statements in your code is unreachable. It also gives a line and column number, precisely indicating where in your code that statement is located. So, fix your code.

Answer (score 2):

It has nothing to do with the added jar.
The statement is unreachable because it is after the `return` statement.
The code will just exit the method with the `return`.